# Excel VBA to Fetch email addresses from inbox and sent items folders

Tags: performance, vba, excel, outlook

I am using the following VBA to fetch multiple specified Email addresses from inbox and sent items folder also including cc and bcc

for eg(gmail.com;yahoo.com) must return all mails having that domain name.

the problem is it takes a whole lot of time and I mean if a person has 2k emails (overall) he might have to wait for approx. 2 hours.

The internet speed isn't an issue and it gives desired output of specified email addresses.

Checked some sources how to make code faster i got to know about restrict function when applied through DASL filter and limit number of items in a loop. I applied the same but the result is still the same and fetching is still slow.
As new into VBA I don't know all about optimization and still learning.

Any other sources or ways to make the fetching and execution faster ?

code given for reference

```
Option Explicit

Sub GetInboxItems()
'all vars declared
    Dim ol As Outlook.Application
    Dim ns As Outlook.Namespace
    Dim fol As Outlook.Folder
    Dim i As Object
    Dim mi As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim n As Long
    Dim seemail As String
    Dim seAddress As String
    Dim varSenders As Variant
      
      'for sent mails
    Dim a As Integer
    Dim b As Integer
    Dim objitem As Object
    Dim take As Outlook.Folder
    Dim xi As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim asd As String
    Dim arr As Variant
    Dim K As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim vcc As Variant
    Dim seemail2 As String
    Dim seAddress2 As String
    Dim varSenders2 As Variant
    Dim strFilter As String
    Dim strFilter2 As String
   'screen wont refresh untill this is turned true
   
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
   'now assigning the variables and objects of outlook into this
    Set ol = New Outlook.Application
    Set ns = ol.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set fol = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set take = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail)
    
    
    
    
    
    Range("A3", Range("A3").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight)).Clear
    
    n = 2
    
    
    strFilter = "@SQL=" & Chr(34) & "urn:schemas:httpmail:fromemail" & Chr(34) & " like '%" & seemail & "'"
    strFilter2 = "@SQL=" & Chr(34) & "urn:schemas:httpmail:sentitems" & Chr(34) & " like '%" & seemail2 & "'"
    'this one is for sent items folder where it fetches the emails from particular people
     For Each objitem In take.Items.Restrict(strFilter2)
    
    
        If objitem.Class = olMail Then
        
            Set xi = objitem
            
            n = n + 1
            
            seemail2 = Worksheets("Inbox").Range("D1")
             varSenders2 = Split(seemail2, ";")
             
              For K = 0 To UBound(varSenders2)
             
             
             'this is the same logic as the inbox one where if mail is found and if the mail is of similar kind then and only it will return the same
                If xi.SenderEmailType = "EX" Then
                    seAddress2 = xi.Sender.GetExchangeUser.PrimarySmtpAddress
                    If InStr(1, seAddress2, varSenders2(K), vbTextCompare) Then
                    Cells(n, 1).Value = xi.Sender.GetExchangeUser().PrimarySmtpAddress
                    Cells(n, 2).Value = xi.SenderName
                    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2), Header:=xlYes
                    On Error Resume Next
                        Range("A3:A9999").Select
                        Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
                     End If
                     'this is the smpt address (regular address)
                     ElseIf xi.SenderEmailType = "SMTP" Then
                    seAddress2 = xi.SenderEmailAddress
                    If InStr(1, seAddress2, varSenders2(K), vbTextCompare) Then
                        Cells(n, 1).Value = xi.SenderEmailAddress
                        Cells(n, 2).Value = xi.SenderName
                       
                       ActiveSheet.UsedRange.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2), Header:=xlYes
                       On Error Resume Next
                           Range("A3:A9999").Select
                           Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
                         End If
                         'this one fetches the cc part recipient denotes cc
                         For j = xi.Recipients.Count To 1 Step -1
                    
                    
                    If (xi.Recipients.Item(j).AddressEntry.Type = "EX") Then
                            vcc = xi.Recipients.Item(j).Address
                            If InStr(1, vcc, varSenders2(K), vbTextCompare) Then
                                Cells(n, 1).Value = xi.Recipients.Item(j).AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser.PrimarySmtpAddress
                                Cells(n, 2).Value = xi.Recipients.Item(j).Name
                            ActiveSheet.UsedRange.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2), Header:=xlYes
                            On Error Resume Next
                           Range("A3:A9999").Select
                           Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
                            End If
                            
                    Else
                    vcc = xi.Recipients.Item(j).Address
                            
                            If InStr(1, vcc, varSenders2(K), vbTextCompare) Then
                                  Cells(n, 1).Value = xi.Recipients.Item(j).Address
                                  Cells(n, 2).Value = xi.Recipients.Item(j).Name
                            ActiveSheet.UsedRange.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2), Header:=xlYes
                            On Error Resume Next
                           Range("A3:A9999").Select
                           Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
                            End If
                            
                            End If
                            
                            Next j
                            
                    Else: seAddress2 = ""
                    End If
                    
                    
                    
                    For a = 1 To take.Items.Count
                    n = 3
                    
                        'this also fetches the recipient emails
                    If TypeName(take.Items(a)) = "MailItem" Then
                    
                    For b = 1 To take.Items.Item(a).Recipients.Count
                        asd = take.Items.Item(a).Recipients(b).Address
                    If InStr(1, asd, varSenders2(K), vbTextCompare) Then
                        Cells(n, 1).Value = asd
                        Cells(n, 2).Value = take.Items.Item(a).Recipients(b).Name
                        n = n + 1
                        End If
                        
                        Next b
                        End If
                        Next a
                    
                    
                    
                    
                    Next K
                    
               End If
        Next objitem
                          
    
    
    For Each i In fol.Items.Restrict(strFilter)
    
        If i.Class = olMail Then
        
            Set mi = i
            'objects have been assigned and can be used to fetch emails
             seemail = Worksheets("Inbox").Range("D1")
             varSenders = Split(seemail, ";")
            
            n = n + 1
            
            For K = 0 To UBound(varSenders)

            'similar logic as above
            
            If mi.SenderEmailType = "EX" Then
                    seAddress = mi.Sender.GetExchangeUser().PrimarySmtpAddress
                    If InStr(1, seAddress, varSenders(K), vbTextCompare) Then
                   Cells(n, 1).Value = mi.Sender.GetExchangeUser().PrimarySmtpAddress
                   Cells(n, 2).Value = mi.SenderName
                    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2), Header:=xlYes
                    On Error Resume Next
                        Range("A3:A9999").Select
                        Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
                        End If
                        
                        
            ElseIf mi.SenderEmailType = "SMTP" Then
                    seAddress = mi.SenderEmailAddress
                    If InStr(1, seAddress, varSenders(K), vbTextCompare) Then
                       Cells(n, 1).Value = mi.SenderEmailAddress
                       Cells(n, 2).Value = mi.SenderName
                       
                       ActiveSheet.UsedRange.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2), Header:=xlYes
                       On Error Resume Next
                           Range("A3:A9999").Select
                           Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
                       End If
                       
                       
                       
                       
                       
        For j = mi.Recipients.Count To 1 Step -1
                    If (mi.Recipients.Item(j).AddressEntry.Type = "EX") Then
                            vcc = mi.Recipients.Item(j).Address
                            If InStr(1, vcc, varSenders(K), vbTextCompare) Then
                                    Cells(n, 1).Value = mi.Recipients.Item(j).AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser.PrimarySmtpAddress
                                    Cells(n, 2).Value = mi.Recipients.Item(j).Name
                            ActiveSheet.UsedRange.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2), Header:=xlYes
                            On Error Resume Next
                           Range("A3:A9999").Select
                           Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
                            End If
                            
                    Else
                    vcc = mi.Recipients.Item(j).Address
                            If InStr(1, vcc, varSenders(K), vbTextCompare) Then
                                   Cells(n, 1).Value = mi.Recipients.Item(j).Address
                                   Cells(n, 2).Value = mi.Recipients.Item(j).Name
                            ActiveSheet.UsedRange.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2), Header:=xlYes
                            On Error Resume Next
                           Range("A3:A9999").Select
                           Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
                            End If
                            End If
                            Next j
                            
    Else: seAddress = ""
     End If
           Next K
        End If
        
        
    Next i
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2), Header:=xlYes
                            On Error Resume Next
                           Range("A3:A9999").Select
                           Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
                           

     Set take = Nothing
     Set mi = Nothing
     

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Your code is really hard to read due to the random indentations and line breaks. Please use the RubberDuck to format your code before posting here. https://rubberduckvba.com/

Choose a style and stick with it. Usually, one line break between logical sections.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Performance

Each statement that references ActiveSheet is affecting the performance/speed. Rather than using the ActiveSheet repeatedly create a named sheet and assign that sheet to a sheet variable. Also create `Range` variables, all of the `Select` statements are affecting the performance. Any `Select` statements should be outside loops if possible.

Use [With statements](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/with-statement) to speed up internal operations.

## DRY Code

There is a programming principle called the [Don't Repeat Yourself Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) sometimes referred to as DRY code. If you find yourself repeating the same code mutiple times it is better to encapsulate it in a function. If it is possible to loop through the code that can reduce repetition as well.

## Complexity

There is only one subroutine, and when I copied the subroutine it was 241 lines long. The general rule in programming is that no function or subroutine should be larger than a single screen in an editor because it is too difficult to understand large subroutines or functions. Break the subroutine up into smaller subroutines or functions that do exactly one thing. Localize the variables to the subroutines they are needed in. There should probably be one subroutine for the `Inbox` and one subroutine for the `Sent mails`.

Another reason to break up the function is that it is very difficult to identify where any bottlenecks are (things that slow down the code) in a large subroutine.

There is also a programming principle called the Single Responsibility Principle that applies here. The [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) states:

> that every module, class, or function should have responsibility over a single part of the functionality provided by the software, and that responsibility should be entirely encapsulated by that module, class or function.

The art or science of programming is to break problems into smaller and smaller pieces until each piece is very simple to code.

Comment: got to know many ways and points from you . will look this things into it .